# Ethics in negotiations

Tags: negotiation, ethics

This is a non-opinion based followup to [a previous question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/14012/listening-in-in-a-negotiations).

What constitutes "good faith" in negotiations?

What behavior during negotiations is considered unethical?

What measures can a party take if they suspect their counterparties of being dishonest?

1. Can one clandestinely record the conversation? E.g., the suspected counterparty talks among themselves in a foreign language, and the one wants to ask his employee (so that the NDA, if any, is not an issue) to listen and translate.
2. Can one clandestinely use [voice-based lie detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_stress_analysis)? Please leave aside the issues of VSA's accuracy - let us assume for the purposes of this question that VSA is 100% accurate.

Comment: I would consider all of the above unethical. Depending onteh jurisdiction, some of it may be illegal as well. I certainly would not do business with anyone I caught doing such a thing.

Comment: @Joe that link is of dubious quality (despite being wikipedia, using phrases like 'ever popular book' suggests bias)

Comment: If the counterparty is either ignorant or culturally conditioned to particular business practices, they may not consider their behavior to be unethical and may not be 'lying' in the sense that a voice lie detector would detect stress markers.  And some people are pathological, and aren't wired for consciousness the way most of you are.  As a general rule, if you have some good reason to doubt your counterparty is reliable, you should simply avoid the relationship - unless you're the CIA and that's all you have to work with.